# Create custom global timezone pipe is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new in Angular, and I'm creating a custom pipe for the timezone to set custom offset values depending on the user-selected timezone.

First, I created timezone.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'timezone' })
export class TimezonePipe implements PipeTransform {
   
    transform(value: string, offset: number): string {
        debugger;
        const date = new Date(Date.parse(value));
        date.setHours(date.getHours() + offset);
        return date.toLocaleString();
      }
}
```

Then, I imported it into app.module.ts to use it globally as:

```
 import { TimezonePipe } from './shared/time-zone/timezone.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [TimezonePipe],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then I want to use it in mycomponent.component.html as:

```
 {{ row.sentDateTime | timezone: -10 }}
```

But it is showing the following error in the console:

> The pipe 'timezone' could not be found in the 'MyComponent' component.
> Verify that it is declared or imported in this module.

and

> MyComponent.component.ts:56 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> null (reading 'factory')

Do you know what I'm doing wrong? my logic says that I need to import to the `.ts` component of that HTML, but it does `app.module.ts` does not do that and is shared in all project?. if not, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Declaring it in the app module doesn't mean you can use it globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name you specified in the pipe is `timezone` while you are using `timeZone` in the template.

Comment: You're right, I changed it, but just getting the same message: The pipe 'timezone' could not be found in the 'MyComponent' component. Verify that it is declared or imported in this module

Comment: Maybe you are using standalone component? Otherwise error message might be true and you are declaring it in another module and do not import.

Comment: Yes, I have `MyComponent.module.ts`, I added to it, and now it's working, thank you so much!